# Explanation on “JavaScript - the Good Parts” memoization example (section 4.15)?

Tags: javascript, closures, memoization

Struggling to understand this code piece from Crockford's book, section 4.15:

```
var memoizer = function (memo, fundamental) {
    var shell = function (n) {
        var result = memo[n];
        if (typeof result !== 'number') {
            result = fundamental(shell, n);
            memo[n] = result;
        }
        return result;
    };
    return shell;
};

var fibonacci = memoizer([0, 1], function (shell, n) {
    return shell(n - 1) + shell(n - 2);
});
```

Question regarding the use of closures here: Once we call the function with an argument, say fibonacci(15), will the memo be available after the function finished executing, or is it just something that makes this particular recursive call more efficient? I.e. if after calling fibonacci(15) I later call fibonacci(16) will memo[15] be there?

Thanks for help.

Comment: yes it will be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will still be there. The array was created when you called `memoizer`, and this will exist as long as your `fibonacci` number existed.

The only way this array would cease to exist is if the `fibonacci` function goes out of scope or is reassigned.

eg

```
var fibonacci = memoizer([0, 1], function (shell, n) {
   return shell(n - 1) + shell(n - 2);
});
var n = fibonacci(15); // the array has grown
n = fibonacci(16); // This used the same array that fibonacci(15) set up

// Now lets lose it
fibonacci = memoizer([0, 1], function (shell, n) {
   return shell(n - 1) + shell(n - 2);
});
// What the hell did you do that for?!? You just recreated the function
// with a new memo array!
n = fibonacci(17); // Had to recreate all of the previous fibonacci numbers again.
```